# Paginator isn't functioning at all

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use a paginator for a project I'm making and I don't see what's wrong with my code but the list isn't getting paginated.

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator


def BlogsList(request):
    blogs=Blog.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(blogs, 5)
    context={
    'blogs':blogs
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html',context)
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Describe the error you see, or the result you see and what you'd expect to see. Note that you're not using your `paginator`, since you don't pass it to your template, you're just passing the `blogs`.

Comment: Also, why not just read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `get_page` method to get the paginated values:

```
def BlogsList(request):  # Please use snake_case for method name(as per pep8 style guide
    blogs=Blog.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(blogs, 5)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    context={
        'blogs':paginator.get_page(page)
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

For more information, please check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view).